# Enumerate Latitude and Longitude from Plist

Tags: iphone, plist, enumeration, cllocationmanager

I want to sort a tableView of places by distance closest to the user. I have three methods (myLocation, clubLocation and enumerate). The lat's and long's are held on a plist (objectatIndex 4 and 5 respectively for the code below). I've created the two arrays, one for lat's and one for long's below in the enumeration method, but I'm having a mental block on how to connect everything together. I would assume the enumerate would return an array (instead of void, that's just a place holder). How can it return two arrays at once? Do I enumerate once for lat and once for long? Please help.

I've updated to have two methods one for Lat and one for Long, how do I return the distances and their associated objects? For example, an array of just distances does me no good, as I need to know which distance is associated to which location?

```
    -(NSArray *)distanceFromLat
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data3" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *latitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    latitudeArray = [[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"Subtree"]objectAtIndex:4];

    NSEnumerator *enumLat = [latitudeArray objectEnumerator];
    id object;

    while ((object = [enumLat nextObject])) {
        [myLocation distanceFromLocation:clubLocation];
    }

}

-(NSArray *)distanceFromLong
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data3" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *longitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    longitudeArray = [[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"Subtree"]objectAtIndex:5];
    NSEnumerator *enumLong = [longitudeArray objectEnumerator];
    id object;

    while ((object = [enumLong nextObject])) {
        [myLocation distanceFromLocation:clubLocation];
    }

}

    -(CLLocation *)clubLocation
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data3" ofType:@"plist"]];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Subtree"];
        NSNumber *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:4]];
        NSNumber *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:5]];
        double clubLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
        double clubLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];
        clubLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:clubLatitude longitude:clubLongitude];
        return clubLocation;

    }

    -(CLLocation *)myLocation
    {
        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
        NSNumber *myLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];
        NSNumber *myLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude];
        double myLatitudeD = [myLatitude doubleValue];
        double myLongitudeD = [myLongitude doubleValue];
        myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:myLatitudeD longitude:myLongitudeD];
        return myLocation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning more than 1 value can be done in at least three simple ways

1. using a custom struct (struct Pair { id first; id second; })
2. using an nsarray to hold both objects
3. using pointers-to-variables as arguments (enumerationWithFirst: (NSArray**) first second: (NSArray**) second

Using Objective-C++ adds a few more options, but these should do.

By the way, using two "enumerator" methods makes more sense. You're essentially returning properties from a simple data structure.

Oh, and please check your code for leaks. There are a few, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I updated the question with two new methods, can you look at these? Also, I know there are memory leaks, I haven't dealt with them yet. Thanks

Comment: I still need some help with the code I updated, if someone could help me out.